# is there's function to extract value from dictionary in list?

Tags: pandas

kindly need to extract name value, even it's Action or adventure from this column in new column
in pandas

```
'[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `from_records`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
df
```

you get

```
    id  name
0   28  Action
1   12  Adventure
2   14  Fantasy
3   878 Science Fiction
```